# what does " return $container->{$resource};" mean

Tags: php

What does the brakets mean and where to read more

```
return $container->{$resource};
```

Comment: Please ignore Safraz' initial answer, as PHP code will never be evaluated when in single quotes. However, this *will* be evaluated: `echo "{$container->$resource}";`. It will be evaluated as the property of object `$container`. The property name is that of which is the value of `$resource`. Your example, however would not give the expected result when put in double quotes. See Yada's answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302531/what-does-return-container-resource-mean/2302545#2302545

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

   $resource = "score";  // set the name dynamically

   return $container->{$resource};  // same as return $container->score;
2. typo / beginner mistake

The programmer meant to type:

```
return $container->resource;  // returns resource public member variable
```

Comment: It's unlikely to be a typo. It would be hard to "mistype" a dollar sign and two brackets and not notice.

Comment: True.  The {} is hard to mis type, but I've seen a lot of bugs where programmer type return $container->$resource;

Answer (score 4):

The brackets are to make use of variable variables. It makes it easier to distinguish between:

```
// gets the value of the "resource" member from the container object
$container->resource;
```

and

```
// gets the value of the "foo" member from the container object
$resource = 'foo';
$container->$resource;
```

You can read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php